# CCSprite comes and after 3 sec it'll remove automatically ?[Done]

Tags: cocos2d-android

I am working on project with cocos2d-android.

What I need this time is : **A CCSprite comes on the screen and stay 3-4 sec and remove automatically. What class is available to do this work**

If anybody have done this thing earlier. Suggest me the way ?

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you code example in Objective-c cause i've never dealt with cocos2d-android, i believe it's pretty straightforward

```
CCSprite *spriteToDisplayAndRemove = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"filename.png"];
[self addChild:spriteToDisplayAndRemove];//say CCLayer adds our sprite
CCDelayTime *delay =  [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:3];
CCCallBlock *block = [CCCallBlock actionWithBlock:^{

   [self removeChild:spriteToDisplayAndRemove];
}];
[self runAction:[CCSequence actions:delay, block, nil]];
```

EDIT:

Since blocks are unavailable in cocos2d-android you might use `CCCallFunc` instead. Again, Objective-c sample:

```
 CCSprite *spriteToDisplayAndRemove = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"filename.png"];
 spriteToDisplayAndRemove.tag = 100;
[self addChild:spriteToDisplayAndRemove];//say CCLayer adds our sprite
CCDelayTime *delay =  [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:3];
CCCallFunc *callFunc = [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(removeSprite)];
[self runAction:[CCSequence actions:delay, callFunc, nil]];
```

And here is your `removeSprite` method:

```
-(void)removeSprite
{
  CCSprite *sprite = [self getChildByTag:100];
  [self removeChild:sprite];
}
```

Comment: CCCallBlock is not available in the library. What is the work of CCCallBlock ?

Comment: it's just a piece of code to be called. you can call any method instead of this block, but using blocks is simpler. is CCCallFunc available?

Comment: I did this the sprite can't remove ... but i m checking .... and I'll tell you about the status ...!!